# Android Studio layout organisation with virtual folders?

Tags: android, layout, directory

The sample project is taken from here. https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples
Under ViewPager2.

In this screenshot, the layouts are organised by its name placed in subfolders. Looking at the directory in finder, I don't see the folder names (e.g. activity_no_tablayout).

How I can do this in new projects? I have a bunch of layout files and I want it to be organised in Android studio without creating real folders.

No real folders but layouts are organised in folders in Android Studio:
[image: No real folders but layouts are organised in folders in Android Studio]

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio aggregate files with the same name and same type, for better control. In this particular case, there is for example `controls.xml` defined both in `/layout` and `/layout-land` which means, you have a different layout for portrait and landscape mode of your device.

If you want to see a real directory hierarchy, switch to Project View instead of Android View:

[image: Android Project View switch]